# How to gain extra access without being system apps on a rooted device?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have a rooted device.

How can I gain extra access without being system app on my rooted device?

For example:

1) gaining permission like : android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

2) executing shell commands as super user

Comment: `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL` is a `signature`-level permission -- neither root nor being on the `system` partition will help you with that.

Comment: I tried to change the protection value of INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL permission from '2' to '1' in /data/system/packages.xml. But the value resets to '2' after device reboot. can we change the protection value? will changing the value work?